# How to show a dialog when local notification comes

Tags: android, android-service, android-notifications, android-alertdialog

This is my code the time gets from the preference and after sets to a proper format of calander and after that execute timertask to set notificatin

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "com.wat.compassapp";
    private SharedPreferences myPrefs;
    int mYear, mMonth, mDay, msecs;
    String fadjrtime, dhuhrtime, asrtime, magrhibtime, ishatime, citygmt;
    private NotificationManager mManager;
    private Context context;
    MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
    Time sqlTime3, fajrsqlTime3, dhuhrsqlTime3, asrsqlTime3, maghribsqlTime3,
            ishasqlTime3;
    static long miliSeconds;
    static Date resultdate;
    Dialog dialog;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    Timer mTimer = new Timer();
    TimerTask mDataTask;
    Calendar c;
    AlertDialog dail;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onCreate");
        myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        mManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        fadjrtime = myPrefs.getString("fadjrtime", null);
        dhuhrtime = myPrefs.getString("dhuhrtime", null);
        asrtime = myPrefs.getString("asrtime", null);
        magrhibtime = myPrefs.getString("magrhibtime", null);
        ishatime = myPrefs.getString("ishatime", null);
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        citygmt = myPrefs.getString("citygmt", null);
        dialog = new Dialog(getApplicationContext());
        // dialog.setContentView(R.layout.)

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                .setTitle("Delete entry")
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK",
                                        1000).show();

                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // do nothing
                            }
                        }).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
        dail = builder.create();
        dail.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
        dail.show();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");


        final Calendar ca = Calendar.getInstance();
        String[] sca = fadjrtime.split(":");
        ca.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(sca[0]));
        ca.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(sca[1]));
        ca.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        SimpleDateFormat ra = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        String fayourTime = Integer.parseInt(sca[0]) + ":"
                + Integer.parseInt(sca[1]) + ":00";

        Date fayourDate;
        try {
            fayourDate = ra.parse(fayourTime);
            fajrsqlTime3 = new Time(fayourDate.getTime());
            Log.d("fajrsqlTime3 on prayerfragment", fajrsqlTime3 + "");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        String[] scal = dhuhrtime.split(":");
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(scal[0]));
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(scal[1]));
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        String dhyourTime = Integer.parseInt(scal[0]) + ":"
                + Integer.parseInt(scal[1]) + ":00";

        Date dhyourDate;
        try {
            dhyourDate = ra.parse(dhyourTime);
            dhuhrsqlTime3 = new Time(dhyourDate.getTime());
            Log.d("dhuhrsqlTime3 on prayerfragment", dhuhrsqlTime3 + "");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final Calendar cale = Calendar.getInstance();
        String[] scale = asrtime.split(":");
        cale.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(scale[0]));
        cale.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(scale[1]));
        cale.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        String asyourTime = Integer.parseInt(scale[0]) + ":"
                + Integer.parseInt(scale[1]) + ":00";

        Date asyourDate;
        try {
            asyourDate = ra.parse(asyourTime);
            asrsqlTime3 = new Time(asyourDate.getTime());
            Log.d("asrsqlTime3 on prayerfragment", asrsqlTime3 + "");
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final Calendar calen = Calendar.getInstance();
        String[] scalen = magrhibtime.split(":");
        calen.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(scalen[0]));
        calen.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(scalen[1]));
        calen.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        String mayourTime = Integer.parseInt(scalen[0]) + ":"
                + Integer.parseInt(scalen[1]) + ":00";

        Date mayourDate;
        try {
            mayourDate = ra.parse(mayourTime);
            maghribsqlTime3 = new Time(mayourDate.getTime());
            Log.d("maghribsqlTime3 on prayerfragment", maghribsqlTime3 + "");
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        final Calendar calend = Calendar.getInstance();
        String[] scalend = ishatime.split(":");
        calend.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, Integer.parseInt(scalend[0]));
        calend.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(scalend[1]));
        calend.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
        String isyourTime = Integer.parseInt(scalend[0]) + ":"
                + Integer.parseInt(scalend[1]) + ":00";

        Date isyourDate;
        try {
            isyourDate = ra.parse(isyourTime);
            ishasqlTime3 = new Time(isyourDate.getTime());
            Log.d("ishasqlTime3 on prayerfragment", ishasqlTime3 + "");
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, "Service running");

        // Log.i("Service running sqlTime3", sqlTime3 + "");
        mDataTask = new MyTimerTask();
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(mDataTask, 0, 1000 /* 60000 */);

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

    }

    private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (citygmt != null) {
                if (citygmt.length() > 0) {

                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone
                            .getTimeZone("GMT"));
                    Log.d("citygmt dsfs", citygmt);
                    c.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(citygmt));
                    System.out.println("The Date in the local time zone "
                            + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                            + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                            + c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                    String yourTime = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                            + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                            + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    // msecs = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    SimpleDateFormat ra = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    Date yourDate;
                    try {
                        yourDate = ra.parse(yourTime);
                        sqlTime3 = new Time(yourDate.getTime());
                        Log.d("sqlTime3 on prayerfragment 1", sqlTime3 + "");
                    } catch (ParseException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putString("citygmt", "");
                    editor.commit();
                } else {
                    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    msecs = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    String yourTime = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                            + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                            + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    msecs = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    SimpleDateFormat ra = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                    Date yourDate;
                    try {
                        yourDate = ra.parse(yourTime);
                        sqlTime3 = new Time(yourDate.getTime());
                        Log.d("sqlTime3 on prayerfragment 2", sqlTime3 + "");
                    } catch (ParseException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            } else {
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                msecs = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                String yourTime = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                        + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                msecs = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                SimpleDateFormat ra = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                Date yourDate;
                try {
                    yourDate = ra.parse(yourTime);
                    sqlTime3 = new Time(yourDate.getTime());
                    Log.d("Service sqlTime3 calenadr",
                            c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":"
                                    + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":"
                                    + c.get(Calendar.SECOND) + "");
                    Log.d("sqlTime3 on prayerfragment 3", sqlTime3 + "");
                } catch (ParseException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            Log.d("Service sqlTime3", sqlTime3 + "");
            Log.d("Service fajrsqlTime3", fajrsqlTime3 + "");
            Log.d("Service dhuhrsqlTime3", dhuhrsqlTime3 + "");
            Log.d("Service asrsqlTime3", asrsqlTime3 + "");
            Log.d("Service maghribsqlTime3", maghribsqlTime3 + "");
            Log.d("Service ishasqlTime3", ishasqlTime3 + "");

            if (sqlTime3.equals(fajrsqlTime3) && !sqlTime3.after(fajrsqlTime3)) {
                // mMediaPlayer.start();
                GenerateNotification(getApplicationContext(), "fajr");
                // dail.show();

            } else if (sqlTime3.after(fajrsqlTime3)
                    && sqlTime3.equals(dhuhrsqlTime3)
                    && !sqlTime3.after(dhuhrsqlTime3)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Service dhuhrsqlTime3");
                // mMediaPlayer.start();
                GenerateNotification(getApplicationContext(), "dhuhr");
                // dail.show();
            }

            else if (sqlTime3.after(fajrsqlTime3)
                    && sqlTime3.after(dhuhrsqlTime3)
                    && sqlTime3.equals(asrsqlTime3)
                    && !sqlTime3.after(asrsqlTime3)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Service asrsqlTime3");
                // mMediaPlayer.start();
                GenerateNotification(getApplicationContext(), "asr");
                // dail.show();
            }

            else if (sqlTime3.after(fajrsqlTime3)
                    && sqlTime3.after(dhuhrsqlTime3)
                    && sqlTime3.after(asrsqlTime3)
                    && sqlTime3.equals(maghribsqlTime3)
                    && !sqlTime3.after(maghribsqlTime3)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Service maghribsqlTime3");
                // mMediaPlayer.start();
                GenerateNotification(getApplicationContext(), "maghrib");
                // dail.show();
            } else if (sqlTime3.equals(ishasqlTime3)
                    && !sqlTime3.after(ishasqlTime3)) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Service ishasqlTime3");
                // mMediaPlayer.start();
                GenerateNotification(getApplicationContext(), "isha");
                // dail.show();
            } /*
             * else if (sqlTime3.after(ishasqlTime3)) { Log.i(TAG,
             * "Service ishasqlTime3"); mMediaPlayer.start();
             * GenerateNotification(getApplicationContext(), "fajr"); }
             */
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void GenerateNotification(Context context, String string) {

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Selectlanguag.class);

        Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.islamiclogo,
                " Prayer time for " + string, System.currentTimeMillis());

        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                context, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "WAT Prayer",
                " Upcoming prayer time is  " + string,
                pendingNotificationIntent);
        Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.wat.compassapp/raw/du");
        notification.sound = path;
        mManager.notify(0, notification);

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        Log.w(TAG, "onDestroy");
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i(TAG, "Service onBind");
        return null;
    }
}
```

I want to show a alertdialog when the notification is appears(for snoozing the notification) i use the system window alert

please help me to write perfect code for this problem

Comment: you want dialog when notification clicked or immediately when notification come?

Comment: immediately when notification comes

Comment: Moved the first description at the top, to make it clear (more clear) what is the code snippet about...

Answer (score 0):

Okay then where you are calling generateNotification method, just use runOnUiThread, and show your dialog here. In your activity make the context static as: static Contaxt context = YourActivity.this;

```
                    ((Activity) YourActivity.context)
                        .runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // place your dialog here

                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Activity not getting in service class

Comment: Okay, in your activity make the context static as: static Contaxt context = YourActivity.this; and then in runOnUiThread use "YourActivity.context" insted of "context" I upadate my ans, try this